# Terminal error relating to babel in react app

Tags: reactjs, github, terminal, dependencies, babeljs

This error seems to have occured out of nowhere. The issue seems to be related to Babel.

The error occurred after making a simple change to my code, a simple caps edit inside of a

tag (which should not create an error), I get the following in message my terminal, without the app loading fully:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/home/Interior.jsx
Error: [BABEL] /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/src/home/Interior.jsx: Cannot find module './helpers/environment.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/index.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform-file.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx/lib/create-plugin.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx/lib/index.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-react/lib/index.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/create.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/scripts/start.js (While processing: "/Users/morganhondros/Documents/ATX Float/atx-float2/trydo/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js")
```

My package.json is also below:

```
{
  "name": "trydo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://trydo.rainbowit.net",
  "basename": "/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "1.6.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.7",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "camelcase": "^5.2.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "emailjs-com": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.1",
    "google-map-react": "^2.2.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "is-wsl": "^1.1.0",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "0.1.0",
    "jest-resolve": "24.7.1",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.3.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.5.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.2.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "7.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.6.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.14.2",
    "react-accessible-accordion": "^3.3.5",
    "react-animate-on-scroll": "^2.1.7",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.4",
    "react-countup": "^4.4.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^9.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.4",
    "react-modal-video": "^1.2.8",
    "react-parallax": "^3.3.0",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scroll-up": "^1.3.7",
    "react-scrollspy": "^3.4.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.24.0",
    "react-tabs": "^3.2.3",
    "react-text-loop": "^2.3.0",
    "react-tilt": "^0.1.4",
    "react-tsparticles": "^1.39.3",
    "react-video-tag": "0.0.10",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "resolve": "1.10.0",
    "sass": "^1.50.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "semver": "6.0.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.2",
    "url-loader": "1.1.2",
    "webpack": "4.29.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.2.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.4.5"
  }
}
```

after checking my babel version, with `npx babel --version`, I see the following:

```
Need to install the following packages:
  babel
Ok to proceed? (y)
```

Take that back, when i type `npm babel --version` I get `8.5.0`

But in my package.json file I see a version of babel installed already with dependencies. Which you can see above.

One last thing, when I go into my github repo i see a bunch of changes in babel files that I don't recall making deliberately.

Any help appreciated.

I was making changes to my app, simple ones that should not have brought about errors, ie making spaces between text in p tags. and I got an error in the terminal and site did not load as normal. I also saw a lot of babel files change in my github commits that I wasn't aware of.